# Iterating through an objects values

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Im working with OOP and looking at how to iterate through an objects values, as an example, this code:

```
var numbers = {
    one: "number one",
    two: "number two",
    three: "number three",
    four: "number four"
};
```

and to iterate through its values, i got this:

```
for(var index in numbers){
    var x = index;
    console.log(numbers[x]);    
}
```

Whilst looking a bit deeper and researching, i saw on mozillla.org that i can also iterate through an objects values like this:

```
console.log(Object.values(numbers));
```

My question is, is there any benefit to one over the other? In everyday programming would one use one over the other?

Comment: There's many different ways to do this and it ends up being simply preference and readability. For instance, you can iterate `Object.keys()` and get the values that way as well

Comment: Depends on in which browsers you want to your code to work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility . It also depends on what you want. If you need to iterate over the properties, then use a loop. If you want an array of values , use `Object.values` (with a polyfill).

Comment: You call this "iterating" ?? http://www.dictionary.com/browse/iterate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop iterates over the an object enumerable properties, including inherited properties. In addition, it's an ES5, and supported by all current browsers.

```js
var obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2 };
var obj2 = Object.create(obj1);
obj2.c = 3;

for (var key in obj2) {
  console.log(obj2[key]);
}
```

[`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) creates an array of the object own properties (not inherited ones), and doesn't iterate them. In addition, since it's an ECMAScript 2017 Draft, IE and older browsers lack support.

```js
var obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2 };
var obj2 = Object.create(obj1);
obj2.c = 3;

console.log(Object.values(obj2));
```

If you want to iterate the object's own properties, and support older browsers, you can use [`Object#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with an array iteration method, such as [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
var obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2 };
var obj2 = Object.create(obj1);
obj2.c = 3;

var result = Object.keys(obj2).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(obj2[key]);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, when you say "inherited properties" what do you mean? i dont mind doing the leg work if you have a link

Comment: Inherited properties are properties that are not assigned directly to the object, but come from a parent in the prototype chain. In my code examples I've create `obj2` out of `obj1`, and the properties that come from `obj1` are inherited by `obj2`. You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Comment: keys + foreach... I dislike this knew trend where you call functions like there is zero cost.

Comment: @procrastinator - if you're going to iterate 10,000 particles, and every nano second counts, you a simple for loop. If you're going to iterate 20 items for a drop list, use something more readable. To make a long story short - use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @procrastinator - the DV should reflect the correctness of the answer, not your likes or dislikes.

Comment: I think it's a bad habit and I'm tired of those "magic" stuffs like reduce, map, keys and ES6... Syntactic sugar that lead to bad performances and ignorance. That's what I think.

Comment: And I respect your opinion. However, I also like the functional style of programming, and the methods you mentioned, and since we're not dealing here with a 100000 properties long object,  your dislike of `Object#keys` or `Array#forEach` is not relevant.